# Is there an Azure Product designed for the RPC or Request/Response pattern between Azure Services?

Tags: azure, rpc, request-response

In a distributed monolith or microservice architecture, what are options to RPC between Web Apps, Container Instances and Function Apps?

I am aware of HTTP based (REST or gRpc) which are not Services per se.
Everything else I am aware of is Request/Reply or a Queue(Service Bus).

Struggling to explain why I am asking this question to forestall low quality comments.  I am guessing the answer is because there is not much value to be added to wrapping an `HttpClient`.  But a solution that uses local-to-azure network addresses alone would be useful.  I would be very happy to hear an answer with a product that I am not aware of.